# VLC multi monitor and multi computer wall output

Tags: multiple-monitors, vlc-media-player, streaming, tv, video-streaming

Lets say we have a 3 x 3 tv monitors (all 1080p) setup with each having their own mini computer. Is there a way to do stream 1 video file such that that 1080p movie is scaled and streamed across all 9 monitors as one image?

Comment: I would do the following: Stream the media from a separated PC. With each minipc, I would connect to the streaming PC, get the whole image, then crop the screen according its wall position. The sync is the good question here.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you'll ever get the sync issues addressed with your solution. I would suggest a proper hardware solution (connecting multiple monitors to a single PC instead).

Check out the [Matrox c900](http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/graphics_cards/c-series/c900/) They aren't exactly cheap, but probably cheaper than nine individual PCs, not to mention the power consumption...